# Insert value into identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following table schema .Insert 100 rows into the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTtable (TEST_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1))
```

I am using SQL Sever 2012

Comment: So What? You aren't even asking what you want to know nor showing what you have done so far. Read the policy. This site is for learning, not for lazy bums.

Comment: It would not put it so harsh, but @EduardoSoriano is right. Read the [ask] and the [faq] please.

Comment: A simple search on google will tell you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Easy: in SQL Server Management Studio, just run this:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable DEFAULT VALUES
GO 100
```

Done!

Comment: Cool stuff!! Good to know

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting Error while inserting values ? if yes then First enable the *Identity Insert* and then insert explicit values.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TESTtable ON

INSERT INTO TESTtable (TEST_ID ) VALUES(3);
INSERT INTO TESTtable (TEST_ID ) VALUES(4);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT TESTtable OFF
```